# How to flip a range horizontally?

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, row, sequence, transpose

I have this google sheets input table
How to flip the range `A2:E` range horizontally with Arrayformula because the range `A1:E` is growing.

```
Input                   Output              
c   a   t                       t   a   c
b   i   r   d               d   r   i   b
h   o   r   s   e       e   s   r   o   h
t   i   g   e   r       r   e   g   i   t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The old way

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A2:E),SEQUENCE(ROWS(
                TRANSPOSE(A2:E))),0))
```

[image]

### The new way

```
=LAMBDA(range,
 TRANSPOSE(SORT(range,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),0)))(TRANSPOSE(A2:E))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`TRANSPOSE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) - [**`SORT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) - [**`SEQUENCE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) - [**`ROWS`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093382) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718)